# What does $\text{PK}=\text{pk}\oplus\text{H}(\text{opk})$ represent in this paper?

Tags: public-key, hash-signature, notation

In Lu, Au and Zhang's 2019 paper [(Linkable) Ring Signature from Hash-Then-One-Way Signature](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/567.pdf), they

> …extend [M. Abe, M. Ohkubo, and K. Suzuki's 2019 [1-out-of-n signatures from a variety of keys](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-36178-2_26.pdf)] framework to its linkable variant. Borrowing the idea from [our previous lattice-based linkable ring signature scheme, [Raptor](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/857.pdf)], we adopt [some] one-time signature scheme ($\Pi^{OTS}$). We build a generic method of constructing linkable ring signature based on $\Pi^{OTS}$ and $\text{Type-H}$ signature with uniform distributed public key. During the key generation procedure, in addition to the public key and secret key pair $(\text{pk},\text{sk})$, each signer also generates a pair of public key and secret key $(\text{opk},\text{osk})$ of a one-time signature. The signer then computes $\text{PK}=\text{pk}\oplus\text{H}(\text{opk})$ for some appropriate hash function $\text{H}(\cdot)$. The new public key is $\text{PK}$ and the secret key is $\text{SK}=(\text{sk},\text{opk},\text{osk})$.

[I take it](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/25441/8287) (perhaps incorrectly in this case) that this symbol, $\oplus$, in that second-to-last equation represents exclusive-or, but how is that implemented here?

They explicitly list RSA as a supported $\text{Type-H}$ signature scheme to underly this linkable ring signature scheme, but this leaves two large questions:

1. how does one use an RSA public key $\text{pk}$, which is an [ordered sequence of two integers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/52127/8287), one of which is *at least* 1024 bits, as an argument to XOR with the output of a hash function such as SHA256, which is merely 256 bits?
2. How would you interpret the (identically random) result of an XOR with a cryptographic hash digest back into such a *particularly* constrained sequence of integers as RSA public key $\text{PK}$? (i.e. the first one must be the product of *exactly* two primes; the second should be less than around 1024 bits) -- and then how would you ensure that $\text{SK}$ comprised its factors?

$\text{PK}_\text{RSA}=\text{pk}_\text{RSA}\oplus\text{SHA-2}_{256}\left(\_\right)$
^ This seems so impossible and ridiculous (despite the authors of this paper listing RSA explicitly as a supported algorithm, and SHA256 being practically "the" standard cryptographic hash) that I am sure I'm misinterpreting something — probably the $\oplus$ symbol, though I cannot fathom what it might mean instead — so, what *is* represented in that line? Am I misinterpreting what $\text{PK}$ represents?

For instance, how would I, "mechanically", (in, say, [`pycryptodome`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/rsa.html)) enact or implement this line, if we take SHA256 as $\text{H}$, RSA as the $\text{Type-H}$ signature scheme, and (say) [Lamport signatures](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/89887/8287) as $\Pi^{OTS}$?

Comment: Can you consider XOF? eXtendible-Output-Functions like SHAkE128 and SHAKE256 that can output desired digest size.

Comment: @kelalaka Setting the hash output size to that of the public key only partially covers (1) — how is this sequence of two integers then to be **serialized** for XORing? — and it leaves (2) unanswered. (I'm, frankly, not even sure if those 2 questions are what I should be asking, though.)

Comment: public key $pk$ is doesn't include $p$ and $q$. RSA public key is just $(n,e)$, nothing more.

Comment: @kelalaka Yes, an RSA public key is a sequence of two integers $(n,e)$. This does not address the question of **what serialization mapping** $(n\in\mathbb{Z}|n=p_\text{prime}q_\text{prime},\mathbb{Z})_\to\{0,1\}^*$ should be done on $pk$ to prepare it for the $\oplus$ operation (can an arbitrary mapping be chosen? anything injective? something particular? I'm trying to figure out what the authors *meant* by this line), as well as how to deserialize the result into a _valid_ $PK$ afterwards.

Comment: (That is, assuming that that operation even represents XOR, and serializing/deserializing a sequence of integers is appropriate or necessary in this case.)

Comment: I really don't see an issue here. $x \oplus x \oplus a= a$

Comment: If you fix the public exponent to a specific value then you could just XOR the modulus with a large enough function H. This could be a XOF or e.g. a MGF (mask generation function), if I understand the question right.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Hmm, fixing the exponent might be *a* solution, but they don't seem to be proposing any modifications to the $\text{KeyGen}$ procedure elsewhere. I may consider e-mailing them if I don't figure this out in a few weeks.

Comment: From a mathematical point of view you'd just get the integer values back from the key gen. How those are encoded is a separate matter that seems to have been skimmed over. However, it is always possible to encode a key into bits; how you do that is probably inconsequential to the security of the scheme and therefore for the paper. Papers generally discuss things on a theoretical level after all. Still, it doesn't hurt to ask!

Answer (score 1):

Reading section III A of the paper (caveat, I've not read the whole paper), it looks like the construction has been generalised so that $H$ maps to the abelian group where the public key operations take place. As such the $\oplus$ operation generalises to the abelian group operation. This notation is unwelcome, but I think in previous work the abelian group in question did combine with XOR.

In the RSA case it would appear that the operation is multiplication modulo $N$ and the hash function maps to $\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z$.